# Width issue for a position absolute div inside a percentage(%) perent div

Tags: html, css

I have two divs, `.div1` & `.div2`, each with a width of 20%. I also have a another div `.bar` inside of `.div1`. This `.bar` div has a positioning of `absolute left 100%`.
I want `.bar` (blue div) to remain at same point at different screen sizes.

[image: Divs]

What would be the procedure to keep the blue bar and gray div in same point with different screen size?

**HTML**

```
<div class="div1">
    <div class="bar">
        This is a Bar
    </div>
</div>
<div class="div2">
    this is Div 2
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.div1{
    background:red;
}
.div2{
     background:#ccc;
     margin-top:25px !important;
}
.div1,.div2{
    position:relative;
    width:20%;
    float:left;
    margin:0px 10px;
    height:180px;
}
.bar{
    background:blue;
    position:absolute;
    left:100%;
    top:0px;
    width:130px;
    z-index:10;

}
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/97s283he/)**

Comment: is this what you are trying to achieve? http://jsfiddle.net/97s283he/1/

Comment: No ! End point of Blue bar and Gray bar should remain in same equal line in every screen. And I see you move the Blue bar inside. It should stay as it is but the Blue and Gray div remain same point in different screen. You can adjust the width of blue div if you want

Answer (score 1):

here you go

http://jsfiddle.net/97s283he/2/

```
.div2{
     background:#ccc;
     left: 100px;
    margin-left: 0px;
}
.div1,.div2{
    position:relative;
    width:20%;
    float:left;
    height:180px;
}
```

Comment: It Should Follow the structure of Image I gave. :(

Comment: Thanks for the try ! But blue bar it still moves in different screen